# SwiperJS - Disable slide after init with function

Tags: javascript, angular, swiper.js

I have a problem with SwiperJS : I have two nested slides, and I want to disable slide in parent when child is active (And enable it for the child), and conversely.

My setup :

```
    this.swiper = new Swiper(containerSelector, {
      width:window.screen.width,
      height:null,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      initialSlide: 1,
      allowTouchMove: true
    });

    this.swiper3 = new Swiper(pictureSelector, {
      width:window.screen.width,
      height:null,
      slidesPerView: 1,
      initialSlide: 0,
      nested:true,
      allowTouchMove: false
    });
```

This is what I try in my function, but it's not work :

```
this.swiper.params.allowTouchMove = true;
this.swiper3.params.allowTouchMove = false;
```

What did I do wrong ?

Thank you all folks !

Answer (score 1):

I've found ! I just have to use directly "allowTouchMove" property like this :

```
this.swiper.allowTouchMove = true;
this.swiper3.allowTouchMove = false;
```

I hope that will help someone someday !